# In C language how numbers are represented internally

Tags: c, numbers

I'm a beginner in C and I have a statement like:

```
printf("%d",(1^6));
```

which produces answer as `7`. I know `^` is the xor operator. I *assume here*, `1` is represented in *4 bits* like `0001` and `6` as `0110`. Doing xor yields the result as `0111` which is `7`.

Is that my assumption is correct? In C language how numbers are represented internally?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two slightly different things to consider here.

The C language standard says that the literals `1` and `6` have type `int`, and that the XOR operation will therefore be performed using the `int` type.

The C language standard also says that the `int` type has a binary representation, with value bits running from least to most significant in increasing powers of 2, plus a sign bit which isn't relevant here because the numbers are both positive, plus optionally some padding bits (and I've never used a C implementation that had any padding bits in `int`).

So in those terms, you're right: `1` is represented as binary `1`, `6` is represented as binary `110`, `7` is `111`, plus there are initial 0s sufficient to make up the size of the type `int`. When writing a binary number we rarely bother to write `00000000000000000000000000000001` even when we know its type is 32 bits.

The number of value+sign bits in an `int` is 32 in most implementations. You might occasionally see 64 or even 16. The standard requires at least 16, but past that it permits any number.

An `int` usually occupies more than one byte of storage. The standard doesn't say whether the least significant bits occupy the first (lowest-addressed) byte, or the last (highest-addressed), or somewhere in the middle. So it allows both little-endian and big-endian representations, and in theory also "middle-endian" representations (I've never seen one of those either, at least not for `int`). Endian-ness relates to the representation of the `int` in memory, but it's irrelevant to the bitwise operations (including XOR), which are defined in terms of the bits in order of significance, not in terms of their order in memory.

That's all in the standard, but the standard also says that it only describes the behavior of an "abstract machine". What your compiler actually *does* is required to have the same result as what the standard says, but there's no requirement for any given code snippet that you'll see those exact representations in memory when the program runs. It would be perfectly legal for a compiler to emit the same code for your line as it would emit for `printf("7");` or even `fputc('7', stdout);`, if it wants to. So there might not be any representation of `1` in the emitted code.

Maybe it will only optimize as far as `printf("%d", 7);`, if `printf` is implemented part of a library and the compiler doesn't bother anticipating what `"%d"` means to that library. Maybe it will do the calculation at runtime, but represent `1` however it thinks is most compact and/or efficient for the target CPU, as long as the compiler has first proved to its own satisfaction that a different size will produce the same result. For example, some instruction sets allow so-called "immediate values", which are small integers stored as part of an instruction. The representation of `1` would still be some number of 0s with a 1 at the end, but because immediates have to fit inside an instruction they'll generally be smaller than `int`.

The exact details of this kind of thing depend on your compiler, target architecture, optimization level, and possibly other compiler options.

Answer (score 3):

Numbers (or rather - *values*) are represented the way the computer is built. If the computer is built using 4-bits words - then that's how you described. Modern computers use 32 or 64 bits per word, and there's big- and little-endian representations.

Also, representation of fractions vary wildly and there are several different standards.

This might also differ between various programming languages (although most use similar conventions and standards).

Eventually its all reduced to bits and bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The number of bits an integer is represented by depends on your architecture - e.g. 32 or 64 bit.

The number 1 is an int, and so in 32-bit architecture is represented by 4 bytes, or 32 bits.

Comment: @Steve - oh, see what you mean now.  I meant 4 bytes which contain 8 bits each, not "8 bits". Oh dear! :)  I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since C is not an interpreted language, there is no "internal representation" of integers (or floating point numbers or characters). There are rules in the C language standard that limit or define how many bits the different types *must* have and the minimum number of bits compared to the other types in the language.

In the end, your architecture affects the number of bits that an integer will have during execution. In this specific case, it might very well be enough with 8 bits but you'll need to inspect the generated machine code/assembler to be sure.